# Has-Many-Through: How to select records with no relation OR by some condition in relation?

Tags: postgresql

There are three tables: `businesses`, `categories`, `categorizations`,

```
CREATE TABLE businesses (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE categorizations (
  business_id integer,
  category_id integer
);
```

So `business` has many `categories` through `categorizations`.

If I want to select businesses without categories, I would do something
like this:

```
SELECT businesses.* FROM businesses
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorizations
ON categorizations.business_id = businesses.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories
ON categories.id = categorizations.category_id
GROUP BY businesses.id
HAVING count(categories.id) = 0;
```

The question is: How do I select businesses without categories AND
businesses with category named "Media" in one query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union:

```
SELECT businesses.* 
FROM businesses
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorizations
ON categorizations.business_id = businesses.id
GROUP BY businesses.id
HAVING count(categorizations.business_id) = 0

UNION 

SELECT businesses.* 
FROM businesses
INNER JOIN categorizations
ON categorizations.business_id = businesses.id
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories.id = categorizations.category_id
WHERE categories.name = 'Media';
```

Note that in the first instance (businesses with no categories at all) that you won't need to join as far as categories - you can detect the lack of category in the junction table. If it is possible for the same business to have the same category more than once, you'll need to introduce the second query with `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
SELECT b.* FROM businesses b
    LEFT JOIN categorizations cz ON b.business_id = cz.business_id
    LEFT JOIN categories cs ON cz.category_id = cs.category_id
    WHERE COALESCE(cs.name, 'Media') = 'Media';
```

... in the hope that `businesses` with no `categorizations` would get NULL entries on their joins.

Comment: D'oh. Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The double-negation trick works for this kind of selections:

```
SELECT * FROM businesses b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM categorizations bc
    JOIN categories c ON bc.category_id = c.category_id
    WHERE bc.business_id = b.business_id
    AND c.name <> 'Media'
    );
```